# if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a diffeomorphism of manifolds with boundary, then $\partial f$ maps $\partial X$ diffeomorphically onto $\partial Y$.

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a diffeomorphism of manifolds with boundary, then $\partial f$ maps $\partial X$ diffeomorphically onto $\partial Y$.

Could anyone give me a hint for the proof of this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at page 57 you'll find the definition of $\partial X$. Then, as usual, get the local diagram for $f$ - here $U$ is an open set in $H^k$ (p.14).

\begin{array}{lcl}
  X & \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} & Y \\
  \downarrow\varphi & & \downarrow\psi \\
  U & \overset{id}{\longrightarrow} & U
\end{array}

Given commutativity of the diagram and the definition of $\partial X$, you should be able to prove it from here.

Comment: what is $ \partial f$  in this case?

Comment: $\partial f$ is $f$ restricted to $\partial X$, which is the image of boundary points in $U$ under $\phi^{-1}$.